# Error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException, When Get Index Database SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Anyoneee Pliss Help, I Want To Show A Data From Database, But When I Run It Say's Error Outofboundsexception, Can Anyone Help Me? The Error Sign In Below

```
public ArrayList<Sma> getPoint(String name)
{
 ArrayList <Sma> point = new ArrayList<Sma>(); 

String selectQuery = "SELECT latitude_sma, longtitude_sma FROM sma WHERE nama_sma ='" + name + "'"; >> FROM HERE I JUST WANT TO SHOW latitude_sma, and longtitude_sma IN A TEXTVIEW
open();
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Sma sekolah = new Sma();
        sekolah.setLatitude(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(latitude_sma)));
        sekolah.setLongitude(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(longtitude_sma)));
        point.add(sekolah);
    } 
    while (c.moveToNext());
}
    return point;
}
```

And here is my Activity

```
 private void handleIntent(Intent intent) 
 {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) 
        {

            dataSource.open();
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            DBDataSource dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
            ArrayList<Sma> list = dataSource.getPoint(query);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);
                    //WHEN I RUN THIS CODE BELOW, THE ERROR HAPPEND > IndexOutOfBounds
            tv.setText(list.get(0).getLongitude().toString());
            tv.setText(list.get(1).getLatitude().toString());
            }
      }
```

Can Anyone Help Me, Please, Thanks B4 :D

Comment: okay" sorry, i forgot to get off my caps lock :D

Comment: You should post a stack trace from logcat which shows where the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply no sure that you have two elements in your list.
try to check before you try to `list.get(0)` or `list.get(1)` it.

```
 ArrayList<Sma> list = dataSource.getPoint(query);
if(list.size()>2){

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);
                    //WHEN I RUN THIS CODE BELOW, THE ERROR HAPPEND > IndexOutOfBounds
            tv.setText(list.get(0).getLongitude().toString());
            tv.setText(list.get(1).getLatitude().toString());


}
```

You can also think about changing your sql statement to sth like this

`Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT latitude_sma, longtitude_sma FROM sma WHERE nama_sma = ?", new String[] {name});`

to check your data in sqlite db please follow it

```
# Switch to the data directory
cd /data/data
# Our application
cd de.vogella.android.todos
# Switch to the database dir
cd databases
# Check the content
ls
# Assuming that there is a todotable file
# connect to this table
sqlite3 yourDBName.db
```

Comment: i'll already do it, but when i run the code.. it's show nothing (blank screen)

Comment: but now throws exception? :) it means that you have any records in db. please check you db rows and execute select via console.

Comment: i already check, the records is avalaible, when i use tv.setText(list.get(0).getLongitude().toString()); the data is showing up.. :)

Comment: check your layout xml, and simply  tv.setText("longitude" + list.get(0).getLongitude().toString() + "latitude" + tv.setText(list.get(1).getLatitude().toString());

Comment: it's say the operator + is undefined for the argument

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are handling your cursor. You will eventually be trying to read column data beyond the last row of the cursor. Use the following idioms instead. (You are also not closing the cursor, which is a separate problem also taken care of by this sample.)

```
ArrayList <Sma> point = new ArrayList<Sma>();
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    cursor = database.rawQuery(...);
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Sma sekolah = new Sma();
        sekolah.setLatitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(latitude_sma)));
        sekolah.setLongitude(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(longtitude_sma)));
        points.add(sekolah);
    }
} finally { 
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
return points;
```

Comment: You really need to post a stack trace from logcat. That will show you where exactly the exception is happening.

Comment: try to see in this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B67EL43g1a_QbmZqbXVlVnZGa0k/edit?usp=sharing